# how to set a trigger to change dates of all related nodes in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, triggers, cypher

How to set a trigger in a way that when the date of a parent node changes -its end date and the start dates of its related nodes change automatically? My trigger looks something like this-

```
CALL apoc.trigger.add(
'update_date',
'UNWIND apoc.trigger.propertiesByKey({assignedNodeProperties},"start_date") as prop
WITH prop.node as n 
match (n)-[:precedes_fs]->(m)
SET n.end_date = apoc.date.toISO8601(apoc.date.add(apoc.date.fromISO8601(n.start_date), 'ms', n.duration, 'd'), "ms")
, m.start_date = apoc.date.toISO8601(apoc.date.add(apoc.date.fromISO8601(n.end_date), 'ms', 1, 'd'), "ms")', {phase:'after'});
```

but my query-

```
match(n) where n.wbs="1.3" set n.start_date="2019-03-19T11:30:00.000Z"
```

is taking too long to execute(no result at all- the query keeps spinning in neo4j browser and nothing in debug log). I am using Neo4j Enterprise version 3.5.4 -  Any suggestions are appreciated

Edit- My node properties look something like this-(all of them have a single label-task)

````
{
  "marked": "false",
  "end_date": "2019-04-25T11:30:00.000Z",
  "parent": "d4e051af-91da-4024-96e7-dfe518ef54980",
  "early_start_date": "2019-03-06T02:30:00.000Z",
  "early_finish_date": "2019-04-25T11:30:00.000Z",
  "late_start_date": "2019-03-06T02:30:00.000Z",
  "wbs": "1",
  "difference": 50,
  "isCritical": false,
  "late_finish_date": "2019-04-25T11:30:00.000Z",
  "text": "Construction of House",
  "id": "d4e051af-91da-4024-96e7-dfe518ef54981",
  "task_type": "project",
  "start_date": "2019-03-06T02:30:00.000Z"
}
{
  "marked": "false",
  "end_date": "2019-04-18T11:30:00.000Z",
  "parent": "d4e051af-91da-4024-96e7-dfe518ef54981",
  "early_start_date": "2019-04-12T02:30:00.000Z",
  "early_finish_date": "2019-04-18T11:30:00.000Z",
  "late_start_date": "2019-04-12T02:30:00.000Z",
  "wbs": "1.9",
  "type": 0,
  "lag": 0,
  "difference": 6,
  "isCritical": false,
  "late_finish_date": "2019-04-18T11:30:00.000Z",
  "text": "Concreting of columns",
  "id": "d4e051af-91da-4024-96e7-dfe518ef549810",
  "task_type": "task",
  "start_date": "2019-04-12T02:30:00.000Z"
}
{
  "marked": "false",
  "end_date": "2019-04-23T11:30:00.000Z",
  "parent": "d4e051af-91da-4024-96e7-dfe518ef54981",
  "early_start_date": "2019-04-19T02:30:00.000Z",
  "early_finish_date": "2019-04-23T11:30:00.000Z",
  "late_start_date": "2019-04-19T02:30:00.000Z",
  "wbs": "1.10",
  "type": 0,
  "lag": 0,
  "difference": 4,
  "isCritical": false,
  "late_finish_date": "2019-04-23T11:30:00.000Z",
  "text": "Shuttering of slab",
  "id": "d4e051af-91da-4024-96e7-dfe518ef549811",
  "task_type": "task",
  "start_date": "2019-04-19T02:30:00.000Z"
}
{
  "marked": "false",
  "end_date": "2019-04-25T11:30:00.000Z",
  "parent": "d4e051af-91da-4024-96e7-dfe518ef54981",
  "early_start_date": "2019-04-24T02:30:00.000Z",
  "early_finish_date": "2019-04-25T11:30:00.000Z",
  "late_start_date": "2019-04-24T02:30:00.000Z",
  "wbs": "1.11",
  "type": 0,
  "lag": 0,
  "difference": 1,
  "isCritical": false,
  "late_finish_date": "2019-04-25T11:30:00.000Z",
  "text": "Reinforcement of slab",
  "id": "d4e051af-91da-4024-96e7-dfe518ef549812",
  "task_type": "task",
  "start_date": "2019-04-24T02:30:00.000Z"
}
{
  "marked": "111",
  "end_date": "2019-03-06T11:30:00.000Z",
  "parent": "d4e051af-91da-4024-96e7-dfe518ef54981",
  "early_start_date": "2019-03-06T02:30:00.000Z",
  "early_finish_date": "2019-03-06T11:30:00.000Z",
  "late_start_date": "2019-04-25T02:30:00.000Z",
  "wbs": "1.12",
  "difference": 0,
  "isCritical": false,
  "late_finish_date": "2019-04-25T11:30:00.000Z",
  "text": "Concreting of slab",
  "id": "d4e051af-91da-4024-96e7-dfe518ef549813",
  "task_type": "task",
  "start_date": "2019-03-06T02:30:00.000Z"
}
{
  "marked": "false",
  "end_date": "2019-03-11T11:30:00.000Z",
  "parent": "d4e051af-91da-4024-96e7-dfe518ef54981",
  "early_start_date": "2019-03-06T02:30:00.000Z",
  "early_finish_date": "2019-03-11T11:30:00.000Z",
  "late_start_date": "2019-03-06T02:30:00.000Z",
  "wbs": "1.1",
  "difference": 4,
  "isCritical": false,
  "late_finish_date": "2019-03-11T11:30:00.000Z",
  "text": "Marking of footing",
  "id": "d4e051af-91da-4024-96e7-dfe518ef54982",
  "task_type": "task",
  "start_date": "2019-03-07T02:30:00.000Z"
}
{
  "marked": "true",
  "end_date": "2019-03-13T11:30:00.000Z",
  "parent": "d4e051af-91da-4024-96e7-dfe518ef54981",
  "early_start_date": "2019-03-12T02:30:00.000Z",
  "early_finish_date": "2019-03-13T11:30:00.000Z",
  "late_start_date": "2019-03-12T02:30:00.000Z",
  "wbs": "1.2",
  "type": 0,
  "lag": 0,
  "difference": 2,
  "isCritical": false,
  "late_finish_date": "2019-03-13T11:30:00.000Z",
  "text": "###",
  "id": "d4e051af-91da-4024-96e7-dfe518ef54983",
  "task_type": "task",
  "start_date": "2019-03-11T11:30:00.000Z"
}
{
  "marked": "true",
  "end_date": "2019-03-19T11:30:00.000Z",
  "parent": "d4e051af-91da-4024-96e7-dfe518ef54981",
  "early_start_date": "2019-03-14T02:30:00.000Z",
  "early_finish_date": "2019-03-19T11:30:00.000Z",
  "actual_start_date": "$$$$",
  "late_start_date": "2019-03-14T02:30:00.000Z",
  "wbs": "1.3",
  "type": 0,
  "lag": 0,
  "difference": 5,
  "isCritical": false,
  "late_finish_date": "2019-03-19T11:30:00.000Z",
  "text": "Footing Reinforcement",
  "id": "d4e051af-91da-4024-96e7-dfe518ef54984",
  "task_type": "task",
  "start_date": "2019-03-14T02:30:00.000Z"
}
{
  "marked": "false",
  "end_date": "2019-03-25T11:30:00.000Z",
  "parent": "d4e051af-91da-4024-96e7-dfe518ef54981",
  "early_start_date": "2019-03-20T02:30:00.000Z",
  "early_finish_date": "2019-03-25T11:30:00.000Z",
  "actual_start_date": "$$$$",
  "late_start_date": "2019-03-20T02:30:00.000Z",
  "wbs": "1.4",
  "type": 0,
  "lag": 0,
  "difference": 5,
  "isCritical": false,
  "late_finish_date": "2019-03-25T11:30:00.000Z",
  "text": "Footing shutteirng",
  "id": "d4e051af-91da-4024-96e7-dfe518ef54985",
  "task_type": "task",
  "start_date": "2019-03-20T02:30:00.000Z"
}
{
  "marked": "false",
  "end_date": "2019-03-26T11:30:00.000Z",
  "parent": "d4e051af-91da-4024-96e7-dfe518ef54981",
  "early_start_date": "2019-03-26T02:30:00.000Z",
  "early_finish_date": "2019-03-26T11:30:00.000Z",
  "late_start_date": "2019-03-26T02:30:00.000Z",
  "wbs": "1.5",
  "type": 0,
  "lag": 0,
  "difference": 0,
  "isCritical": false,
  "late_finish_date": "2019-03-26T11:30:00.000Z",
  "text": "Footing Concreting",
  "id": "d4e051af-91da-4024-96e7-dfe518ef54986",
  "task_type": "task",
  "start_date": "2019-03-26T02:30:00.000Z"
}
{
  "marked": "false",
  "end_date": "2019-04-01T11:30:00.000Z",
  "parent": "d4e051af-91da-4024-96e7-dfe518ef54981",
  "early_start_date": "2019-03-27T02:30:00.000Z",
  "early_finish_date": "2019-04-01T11:30:00.000Z",
  "late_start_date": "2019-03-27T02:30:00.000Z",
  "wbs": "1.6",
  "type": 0,
  "lag": 0,
  "difference": 5,
  "isCritical": false,
  "late_finish_date": "2019-04-01T11:30:00.000Z",
  "text": "Backfilling",
  "id": "d4e051af-91da-4024-96e7-dfe518ef54987",
  "task_type": "task",
  "start_date": "2019-03-27T02:30:00.000Z"
}
{
  "marked": "false",
  "end_date": "2019-04-05T11:30:00.000Z",
  "parent": "d4e051af-91da-4024-96e7-dfe518ef54981",
  "early_start_date": "2019-04-02T02:30:00.000Z",
  "early_finish_date": "2019-04-05T11:30:00.000Z",
  "late_start_date": "2019-04-02T02:30:00.000Z",
  "wbs": "1.7",
  "type": 0,
  "lag": 0,
  "difference": 3,
  "isCritical": false,
  "late_finish_date": "2019-04-05T11:30:00.000Z",
  "text": "Reinforcement of columns",
  "id": "d4e051af-91da-4024-96e7-dfe518ef54988",
  "task_type": "task",
  "start_date": "2019-04-04T02:30:00.000Z"
}
{
  "marked": "false",
  "end_date": "2019-04-11T11:30:00.000Z",
  "parent": "d4e051af-91da-4024-96e7-dfe518ef54981",
  "early_start_date": "2019-04-08T02:30:00.000Z",
  "early_finish_date": "2019-04-11T11:30:00.000Z",
  "late_start_date": "2019-04-08T02:30:00.000Z",
  "wbs": "1.8",
  "type": 0,
  "lag": 0,
  "difference": 3,
  "isCritical": false,
  "late_finish_date": "2019-04-11T11:30:00.000Z",
  "text": "Shuttering of columns",
  "id": "d4e051af-91da-4024-96e7-dfe518ef54989",
  "task_type": "task",
  "start_date": "2019-04-08T02:30:00.000Z"
}
```[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGLEe.png
````

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are updating a property in the trigger which is causing the trigger to fire again thus getting into an infinite cycle. That's why it doesn't return.

There is an experimental Graphaware triggers module that may just work for your case, https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-triggers